# Microsoft Graph API beta not working with node

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm having trouble to use the beta api of Microsoft Graph.

Running this code on v1.0 works fine

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;
var MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
require("isomorphic-fetch");

var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
    //defaultVersion: 'beta',
    authProvider: function (done) {
        done(null, 'mytoken');
    }
});

client
    .api('/users')
    .version('v1.0')
    .get()
    .then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
})["catch"](function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Running this code on beta doesn't work. There is no output at all, no error, no response...

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;
var MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
require("isomorphic-fetch");

var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
    //defaultVersion: 'beta',
    authProvider: function (done) {
        done(null, 'mytoken');
    }
});

client
    .api('/applications')
    .version('beta')
    .get()
    .then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
})["catch"](function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If I call the beta/applications endpoint with postman it works.

Do you have any idea why is this happening and why I'm not having any output.

**UPDATE**

NPM package 1.5.2 is not working. 1.4.0 is working...

**UPDATE 2**

I authenticate as an application, so doing /beta/me is giving back a 404.

I'm using node v11.11.0

Comment: Although I don't have permissions for getting the /applications, am getting same insufficient privilege error in both versions ? is this happening only for /applications or all the beta/* urls ?

Comment: all beta urls are not working I think. I tried a few and got nothing.

Comment: its working fine with my environment. I have tried with "/me". Can you verify with the "/me" ? Can you help me in reproducing the issue by your request environment ? if its in node then the node version or if it is in browser environment, then by the browser name and its version?

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: Can you share error message in the 404? please remove PI information if any.